# how to test yourself on knowledge of Ruby/ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a list of questions for self-validation. Looking at that I can be sure that I know. And that I should brush up on.
While I'm learning I make a list like that, but it contains only items I've heard somewhere. And it's take a while when I will find something new.

Comment: Here is the biggest list of Ruby questions from beginner to expert I have ever seen :: http://shawnlindsey.com/blog/ruby-test-questions-the-great-big-ruby-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javabelt have a ruby certification program in development: you can find it [here](http://jira.javablackbelt.com/QuestionnaireDefDisplay.wwa?questPublicId=01548). Last time I looked it was still in development, and also it is hard for non full-on java developers (like myself) to get enough contribution points to actually take any test.

On Brainbench now, finally, [a Ruby exam](http://brainbench.com/xml/bb/common/testcenter/taketest.xml?testId=2865) is in development. You can now take it for free. It is still a beta-test.

An alternative approach would be to follow all ruby/ruby-on-rails questions on stackoverflow, and doing your best to find answers for the harder questions (some questions will be too specific, concerning usage of specific gems), but a lot of questions are really interesting just to try and find the answer for yourself.

Have fun!

Comment: In addition to the tests I was referring to questions of self-checking
Ex. What the difference between `require` and `link`? Between `Module` and `Class`? and so on

Answer (score 5):

**Following are few list of tests for ruby and Rails both.**

- Name of Certificate: **Ruby on Rails**

  Who is providing: oDesk Incorporation

  Cost of certification: **Free**

  website : https://www.odesk.com/tests/985?pos=0

---

- Name of Certificate: **Ruby on Rails**

  Who is providing: Techgig.com(Times Business Solutions Limited
  (TBSL))

  Cost of certification: **Free**

  website : http://www.techgig.com/skill/rubyonrail

---

- Name of Certificate: **Ruby 1.9**

  Who is providing: BrainBench

  Cost of certification: $49.9

  website :
  https://www.prometric.com/en-us/clients/ruby/Pages/landing.aspx

---

- Name of Certificate: **Ruby Association Certified Ruby
  Programmer(Ruby 1.8.7)**

  Who is providing: Ruby Association

  Cost of certification: $150

  website :
  http://brainbench.com/xml/bb/common/testcenter/consumer/taketest.xml?testId=2967

---

- Name of Certificate: Ruby on Rails

  Who is providing: Smarterer

  Cost of certification: Free

  website : http://smarterer.com/tests/ruby-on-rails

---

- Name of Certificate: Ruby

  Who is providing: Smarterer

  Cost of certification: Free

  website : http://smarterer.com/tests/ruby

---

- Name of Certificate: Ruby

  Who is providing: Code School

  Cost of certification: Paid

  website :
  https://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-testing-for-zombies

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can find something useful here - http://www.indiangeek.net/wp-content/uploads/Programmer%20competency%20matrix.htm

Comment: I know about Programmer's competency matrix but it about common programming, but I try find about ruby. Would be awesome to find ruby competence matrix)

Comment: I'm also ruby fan and I'm going to start learning asp.net within my university course. so we're kinda mates.

Answer (score 2):

For ruby I found this one:
http://www.rexaminator.com/
It's still beta.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the community-driven [blackbeltfactory](http://www.blackbeltfactory.com) site a great learning resource.  The topic lists for exams are good for giving you that list of things you might not even know you don't know yet.

They started focused on Java but are broadening out. No RoR courses/exams yet but there is a [Ruby - basic](http://www.blackbeltfactory.com/QuestionnaireDefDisplay.wwa?questPublicId=01548).

Answer (score 0):

I want to test my Ruby and Rails knowledge and then start documenting myself, to improve my knowledge about Ruby on Rails and Ruby

All the documentation above was not really good

This are the websites I found. Maybe we should get a good list of documentation where people can test their skills

https://www.interviewcake.com/

http://www.codequizzes.com/